# Proving that there exists a natural number m such that each eigenvalue of A is an m-th root of unity

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

This question is from a masters exam for which I am preparing and I was unable to solve this.

> Let A and X be invertible complex matrices such that $X AX^{-1} = A^2$. Prove that there exists a natural number m such that each eigenvalue of  A is an m-th root of unity.

If $\lambda_i$ is an eigenvalue of A then it satisfies $|AX-\lambda_i X|=0$ but I am unable to think how should I use $X AX^{-1} = A^2$ in the equation. So, can you please help?

Comment: The property you have stated is not the definition of eigenvalue. Starting with the definition should help, as also thinking about what happens to the length of an eigenvector under the transformations on each side.

Comment: In the Related posts in the sidebar to the right, it seems like there's a duplicate: "If for invertible matrices $A$ and $X$, $XAX^{-1}=A^2$ then eigenvalues of $A$ are $n^{th}$ roots of unity."